# Rsquare best fit line in actual and precited scatter plot with d3.js/chart.js/highcharts

Tags: typescript, charts, highcharts, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I wanted to draw rSquared best fit line in scatter plot of actual and predicted values , where I was given the rsquare value , I first thought of to use ag grid chart , but could not find a way , so thinking of using any of the js chart package (d3.js , chart.js , highcharts.js) is it possible to draw this rsquare line in scatter plot .
for reference I added data in this plunkr , but used ag grid chart but could not find any way to do that .

```
  rsquared: number = 0.987;
```

plunkr code
https://plnkr.co/edit/rhQfOrHRQGwD7TrZ?preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find 2 articles that may help you on how to do it in Highcharts:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/data-science-and-highcharts-linear-regression/
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/calculating-and-drawing-a-linear-regression-using-highcharts/

```
  function (data) {
    function regression(arrWeight, arrHeight) {
      let r, sy, sx, b, a, meanX, meanY;
      r = jStat.corrcoeff(arrHeight, arrWeight);
      sy = jStat.stdev(arrWeight);
      sx = jStat.stdev(arrHeight);
      meanY = jStat(arrWeight).mean();
      meanX = jStat(arrHeight).mean();
      b = r * (sy / sx);
      a = meanY - meanX * b;
      //Set up a line
      let y1, y2, x1, x2;
      x1 = jStat.min(arrHeight);
      x2 = jStat.max(arrHeight);
      y1 = a + b * x1;
      y2 = a + b * x2;
      return {
        line: [
          [x1, y1],
          [x2, y2]
        ],
        r
      };
    }
```